# How to link to another page using react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am able to navigate from a page to another by using typing direct url, however when I try to click a button that links to another page, I have to refresh the page. It doesn't update the page itself, just changes URL on my browser.
NOTE: This is just for /chart/:sym route, all other routes work perfectly. Here is the code:
App.js:

```
<Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/user" component={BoardUser} />
            <Route path="/mod" component={BoardModerator} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={BoardAdmin} />
              <Route exact path="/chart">
                  <Chart symbol='nkla'/>
              </Route>
//BELOW IS WHERE THE PROBLEM HAPPENS
            <Route path="/chart/:sym">
                  <Chart symbol=''/>
              </Route>
          </Switch>
```

Here is where I link to this page:

```
export default function Chart(props) {
  const { sym } = useParams();
  const [symbol, setsymbol] = useState(sym);
  const [curSelection, setcurSelection] = useState("intraday-prices");
  const [isLoaded, setisLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [data, setdata] = useState({});
  const [error, seterror] = useState(null);
  const [gainers, setgainers] = useState([]);
function toggle() {
    //setcurSelection(select)
    // this.setState({curSelection:select})
    console.log("test")
    
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/${symbol}/${curSelection}?token=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          let chartData = [];
          let chartLabels = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i].average !== null) {
              if(curSelection!="intraday-prices"||(curSelection=="intraday-prices"&&i%5==0)) {
                chartData.push(result[i].close.toFixed(2));
                chartLabels.push(result[i].label);
              }
            }
          }
          setisLoaded(true);
          setdata({  
            labels: chartLabels,
            datasets: [
            {
              label: symbol,
              fill: false,
              lineTension: 0.1,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
              borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
              borderWidth: 1,
              data: chartData
             }
           ]})
        },
        (error) => {
          setisLoaded(true);
          seterror(error)
          
        }
      )
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/market/list/gainers?token=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setgainers(result)
          console.log(result);
        })
    toggle()
},[curSelection])

    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{display:"flex"}}>

        {gainers.slice(-5).map((element)=>{

          return <div key={element.symbol} className="card" style={{width: "25rem",margin:10,paddingLeft:2,paddingTop:2}}>
            <Link to={"/chart/"+element.symbol}>
              <p>{element.symbol}</p>
              </Link>
              </div>})}
        </div>
<button className="btn btn-primary" style={{margin:10}} onClick={() => setcurSelection("chart/ytd")}>YTD</button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{margin:10}} onClick={() => setcurSelection("chart/2y")}>2 year</button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{margin:10}} onClick={() => setcurSelection("chart/5y")}>5 year</button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{margin:10}} onClick={() => setcurSelection("chart/1y")}>1 year</button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{margin:10}} onClick={() => setcurSelection("chart/1m")}>1 month</button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{margin:10}} onClick={() => setcurSelection("chart/6m")}>6 month</button>
```

Here is index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive code example? Where are the links rendered in relation to the router and routes? The `Chart` component is rendered on more than one path, so it likely needs to handle prop updates. Can you also include the `Chart` component? Do you have any logic anywhere that handles the match param `sym` from `"/chart/:sym"`?

Comment: updated it. also, I use this to get the sym in the beginning of the function:const { sym } = useParams();
  const [symbol, setsymbol] = useState(sym);

Comment: Also, the links are in the Chart component also, basically I am trying to link from a chart to another using links.

Comment: Very well, so can you include your `Chart` component so we may see how it handles trying to link to other routes and/or reacting to it's own route changes?

Comment: To be honest, because I am still in the learning and testing phase, this is not a component but a whole class(well, function since I am using react hooks). I am updating the answer again to show that

Comment: OK, I think I have included everything that you will need

Comment: Look into the properties of `BrowserRouter`, specifically, [forceRefresh](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The main issue here is that the `Chart` component doesn't react to new updated match param values. In other words, when the route changes and `sym` is a new value it doesn't update anything in the component. The forced page reloading is essentially remounting the component so the state is "reinitialized" with the new current `sym` match param.

## Solution

Use an additional `useEffect` hook to "listen" for updates to `sym` and update the `symbol` state.

```
export default function Chart(props) {
  const { sym } = useParams();
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState(sym);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSymbol(sym);
  }, [sym]);

  ...
```

If there is any code that has a dependency on `symbol` state then you may need additional effects for them.

Comment: Right on! That solved the issue, I appreciate it.